# How do you build Springboot with Bazel?

Tags: spring-boot, bazel

I am wondering if there is already Springboot application that is open-sourced where Bazel build tool is included.

Comment: This springboot rule seems to be the best source at the moment:
https://github.com/mobichord/rules_springboot

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you searching for, but if you want to create a spring-boot from scratch using bazel this post could result useful for you https://www.pgrs.net/2015/09/01/migrating-from-gradle-to-bazel/